# Javascript replace?

Tags: javascript, replace

```
<script>
var text = "a's ..a's ...\"... ";
text = convert(text);
function convert( text )
{
    var n = text.replace(/\'/g, "&#039;");
    n = text.replace(/\"/g,"&quot;");
    return n;

}
console.log(text);
document.write(text);

</script>
```

The problem is that when it replace the second time it take doesnt "remember" what it replaced the first time, so only the last replace is returned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you are replacing the *original* `text` string in the second `replace`, instead of `n`, which is the value of the *replaced* text:

```
function convert( text )
{
    var n = text.replace(/\'/g, "&#039;");
    n = n.replace(/\"/g,"&quot;");
    return n;
}
```

`replace` does ***not*** modify your original string. Instead, it returns a ***new*** modified string . You can also do both replaces in a single statement:

```
return text.replace(/\'/g, "&#039;").replace(/\"/g,"&quot;");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function convert( text )
{
    var n = text.replace(/\'/g, "&#039;");
    // Wrong: n = text.replace(/\"/g,"&quot;");
    // This modifies the previously edited variable.
    n = n.replace(/\"/g,"&quot;");
    return n;

}
```